# vim - replace multiple words with yanked text, multiple times

Tags: vim

In the text below, if I want to replace `book1` and `book2` with `pen` I could yark `pen` and go to the beginning of the 2 and 3 lines and hit . (dot) to replace the words.

```
pen;
book1;
book2;
book3;
```

but, how can I replace multiple words with yanked text? For example, I want to replace `book 1` and `book 2` with `pen`

Before:

```
pen;
book 1;
book 2;
book 3;
```

After:

```
pen;
pen;
pen;
book 3;
```

Is it possible to replace `book 1` and `book 2` without yanking the word `pen` twice? Maybe a keybind you think is good?

Comment: Using vi to edit is certainly normal and on-topic here. Feel free to delete here and re-ask at vi.SE if you'd prefer, though.

Answer (score 2):

I need this so often, I wrote a plugin to simplify and allow maximum speed: [ReplaceWithRegister](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2703).

This plugin offers a two-in-one `gr` command that replaces text covered by a {motion} / text object, entire line(s) or the current selection with the contents of a register; the old text is deleted into the black-hole register, i.e. it's gone. It transparently handles many corner cases and allows for a quick repeat via the standard `.` command. Should you not like it, its page has links to alternatives. (It works just like @s1n7az's snippet, but as a plugin is more sophisticated and robust.)

Answer (score 1):

[This reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/daf2s3/replace_multiple_words_with_yanked_text_multiple/f1pddgq?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) is the best solution I got. Pretty neat.

> I defined a command to substitute text without changing default
>   register. Maybe this will serve you too. It might be based on this or
>   this, I don't really remember where I got the idea, but I saw it
>   somewhere before implementing.
>
> ```
> nnoremap <silent> cp :let g:substitutemotion_reg = v:register
>             \ <bar> set opfunc=SubstituteMotion<CR>g@
>
> " substitute {motion} text with contents of a register function!
> SubstituteMotion(type, ...)
>     let l:reg = g:substitutemotion_reg
>     if a:0
>         " visual mode, use '< and '> marks
>         silent exe "normal! `<" . a:type . "`>\"_c\<c-r>" . l:reg . "\<esc>"
>     elseif a:type == 'line'
>         " linewise
>         silent exe "normal! '[V']\"_c\<c-r>" . l:reg . "\<esc>"
>     elseif a:type == 'block'
>         " blockwise-visual
>         silent exe "normal! `[\<C-V>`]\"_c\<c-r>" . l:reg . "\<esc>"
>     else
>         " characterwise
>         silent exe "normal! `[v`]\"_c\<c-r>" . l:reg . "\<esc>"
>     endif endfunction
> ```
>
> To use it, type something like cpi( which will lead to replacement of
>   the text within closest pair of parenthesis with the contents of
>   default register.